# Python Query ( string)

Tags: python, pyqt

I am working with python plugins.I have my **field** variable = **"t_0"."survey"** I wanted to store only **survey** into another variable.Which function to use to get **survey** from **"t_0"."survey"**?

I tried `a=field.split(".")` when i try to print **a** ,it gives

```
<PyQt4.QtCore.QStringList object at 0x01247228>
```

Is there any delete function or to find position of "." from the string..?

If i try **lstrip()** or **ljust()**  ,it gives error saying

```
AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'lstrip'..
```

Comment: Possibly just try a=str(field) b=a.split(".")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a` is a `QString`, then calling `a.split` produces a `QStringList`, just as calling `split` on a Python `str` produces a `list`:

```
>>> qstr = QString("t_0.survey")
>>> slist = qstr.split(".")
>>> slist
<PyQt4.QtCore.QStringList object at 0x00BBCD88>
```

You can either cast `QStringList` to a Python list:

```
>>> list(slist)
[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u't_0'), PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'survey')]
```

or just extract the second element:

```
>>> slist[1]
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'survey')
```

And perhaps get rid of the `QString` wrapping:

```
>>> unicode(slist[1])
u'survey'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `field` variable is of type `QString` the below code works fine for me.

```
 QString str = "a,b,c";    
 QStringList list1 = str.split(",");
```

Output = `[ "a","b", "c" ]`

Try doing `type(field)` in your python interpreter and show us the output.

OR type cast your variable to `str` like this `a=str(field).split(".")`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like 'a' is not really a String, but some other object generated by the PyQt library (maybe an input field ?). If you can find a way to get a real String out of this field (a.value(), a.text(), or something like that), you should be able to use split.